# Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `use_native_modules!' for #<Pod::Podfile:0x007fd5795662a0>

Tags: ios, react-native, cocoapods

I just switch from a MacBook Air with the Intel Processor to a MacBook Pro with the M1 Processor, and now I am unable to do **anything** with Podfile or `pod install.` I keep getting errors like this...

```
Invalid `Podfile` file: undefined method `use_native_modules!' for <Pod::Podfile:0x007fd5795662a0>.
```

Keep in mind the exact same Podfile worked on my Intel Chip, and it works for my coworker on his M2. I was originally having issues with `/scripts/autolinking` so I took all traces of that out of my code too.

I gave up on this, and tried to just make an entirely fresh react native repo, and STILL am unable to do anything with pods. After creating the new native app, I wwas given the following message in the terminal...

```
Error: Failed to install CocoaPods dependencies for iOS project, which is required by this template.
Please try again manually: "cd ./KidzNMotionNative/ios && pod install".
```

Keep in mind, I've run the commands to install cocoapods and I have it.
When I try to listen to that message, cd into the right repo and run `pod install` I get the following mess of an error

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: /Users/nicklanese/Documents/toBeMoved/KidzNMotionNative/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:39: syntax error, unexpected <<
    template =<<~EOS
                ^
/Users/nicklanese/Documents/toBeMoved/KidzNMotionNative/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:40: unknown regexp options - ll
/Users/nicklanese/Documents/toBeMoved/KidzNMotionNative/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: dynamic constant assignment
        RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
                                         ^
/Users/nicklanese/Documents/toBeMoved/KidzNMotionNative/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: `$(' is not allowed as a global variable name
/Users/nicklanese/Documents/toBeMoved/KidzNMotionNative/node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods_utils/script_phases.rb:41: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input
        RCT_SCRIPT_POD_INSTALLATION_ROOT=$(pwd)
```

Which makes NO SENSE because React Native generated the Podfile for me. So what gives?